# Regex string split give priority to one character over another

Tags: java, regex

I know there are plenty of regex posts, but I am unable to find exactly what I need. I am creating a calculator app, for which I have an equation that I need to tokenize according to the operators present in the equation.

Examples:

"123x849-302+450" -> ["123", "849", "302", "450"]

"124x(145+301)x402+(-402)" -> ["124", "145+301", "402", "-402"]

"124x((234+403)/354))+(-21)" -> ["124", "(234+403)/354", "-21"]

Basically, if there are parentheses, I need to get the token inside the parentheses, otherwise just split according to the operator.

I am very bad with regex, and only know the very basics. I don't have a clue how to include the parentheses in the regex and right now, all I have got is this:

```
String delim = "[x+/-]";
String[] tokens = equation.toString().split(delim);
```

The toString exists because equation is a StringBuilder.

Comment: Perhaps it's not a regexp that you need...

Comment: What else could I use? A Pattern matcher? I am unfamiliar with that as well.

Comment: I would use a recursive descent parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a 'regular' syntax is an academic notion. 'Regular expressions' are properly named: They can parse any 'regular' syntax, but they cannot be used to parse non-regular syntax.

Let's define 'basic maths' as a mix of numbers, the 4 operators: `+-*/`, and parentheses.

'basic maths' is **not regular**.

It therefore cannot be parsed with regular expressions.

What you want is a parser that can turn this:

```
a+x*y+(b-c)*e
```

into this data structure:

```
          PLUS
      /           \
    PLUS          TIMES
  /     \         /     \
a      TIMES    MINUS   e
      /   \    /  \
      x   y    b   c
```

Various parser techs can, such as recursive descent or packrat (for example using the grappa/parboiled parser library), and various LALR and LL(k) based parsing techs, such as ANTLR. Generally those are very complex bits of technology; perhaps for something this trivial you can write your own recursive descent based parsing for this.

But, getting back to your original question, if you want to split `a+x*y+(b-(g+h))*e` up into: ['a', 'x', 'y', '(b-(g+h))', 'e'], which is only part of what you need ,as now you still need to work out what to do with the '(b-(g+h))' node, a regex simply cannot do this: You want your regex to see the opening `(` right before the `b` as the start of a parenthesis block, and then.... your regex has to COUNT the number of opening parens, and then find as many closing parens and ignore those, and then the closing paren after those wins out. So, this regular expression:

```
String elementPattern = "(\\([^\\)]+\\)|[^-+*/\\(\\)]+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\s*" + elementPattern + "(\\s*[-+*/]\\s*" + elementPattern + ")*$");
```

which at first glance appears to do the job, can't actually do the job: It would stop considering the `(b-(g+h))` part at the *FIRST* of the 2 closing parens, and thus fails to match. It needs to stop at the second but regular expressions don't have any way to do that, because that is not 'regular'.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! I will read up on recursive decent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a regexp would be the right tool. I don't know what the end goal is, but if you just need to split the expression as in you question, you can try something like this:

```
private static List<String> splitExpr(String expr) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    int level = 0;
    int st = 0;
    for (char c: expr.toCharArray()) {
        if (level > 0) {
            // we're in a subexpression
            if (c == '(') {
                ++level;
            } else if (c == ')') {
                --level;
            }
            if (level == 0) {
                result.add(buf.toString());
                st = 2;
            } else {
                buf.append(c);
            }
        } else {
            switch (st) {
                case 0:
                    // initial state
                    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                        // first digit of a number
                        buf.setLength(0);
                        buf.append(c);
                        st = 1;
                    } else if (c == '(') {
                        // beginning of a subexpression
                        buf.setLength(0);
                        ++level;
                    } else {
                        // error: ignore unexpected character
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // inside a number
                    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                        // next digit
                        buf.append(c);
                    } else if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == 'x' || c == 'X'
                            || c == '/') {
                        // operator; the number is finished, add it to the list
                        result.add(buf.toString());
                        st = 0;
                    } else {
                        // error: ignore unexpected character
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // after a subexpression
                    if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == 'x' || c == 'X'
                            || c == '/') {
                        st = 0;
                    } else {
                        // error: ignore unexpected character
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (level == 0 && st == 1) {
        // in a number at the end of string: add the number to the list
        result.add(buf.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

for your examples:

```
123x849-302+450: [123, 849, 302, 450]
124x(145+301)x402+(-402): [124, 145+301, 402, -402]
124x((234+403)/354))+(-21): [124, (234+403)/354, -21]
```